# How to insert the title of the page as a class in page title block?

Tags: theming, 8

I am new to Drupal 8 theming and I've been long time trying the following:

I want to add classes to page-title in the template, `page-title.html.twig`. Two new classes:

1.- 'page_title'

2.- The real title of the page

The code I'm using is,:

```
{{ title_prefix }}

{%
set classes = [
'page-title',
title|clean_class
]
%}

{% if title %}
<h1{{ title_attributes.addClass( classes ) }}>{{ title }}</h1>
{% endif %}

{{ title_suffix }}
```

it renders:

```
<h1 class="js-quickedit-page-title page-title array">FORMACIÓN: CURSOS Y  TALLERES</h1>
```

The string 'page-title' is working well but the variable title provoke an error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::getClass() (line 72 of
>   core\lib\Drupal\Component\Utility\Html.php).

And print the class, array.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Seems `title` is a render array. You probably have to use `title.value` instead. But I'd recommend to simply preprocess that and leave the templates untouched.

You can implement [`hook_preprocess_hook`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x) and then use [`TitleResolver::getTitle`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Controller%21TitleResolver.php/function/TitleResolver%3A%3AgetTitle/8.4.x) and [`Html::cleanCssIdentifier`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Html.php/function/Html%3A%3AcleanCssIdentifier/8.2.x) to do what you want from inside your theme's `*.theme` file or from within a custom module's `*.module` file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {

  // This won't work properly with Twig debugging enabled.
  // $title = $variables['title'];

  // Here is a safer method to get the current title.
  $request = \Drupal::request();
  $route_match = \Drupal::routeMatch();
  $title = \Drupal::service('title_resolver')->getTitle($request, $route_match->getRouteObject());

  $css_title = \Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::cleanCssIdentifier($title);
  $variables['title_attributes']['class'][] = 'page-title';
  $variables['title_attributes']['class'][] = strtolower($css_title);
}
```

---

You can use nearly the exact same snippet to add that CSS class to the `<body>` tag:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  $request = \Drupal::request();
  $route_match = \Drupal::routeMatch();
  $title = \Drupal::service('title_resolver')->getTitle($request, $route_match->getRouteObject());

  $css_title = \Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::cleanCssIdentifier($title);
  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = strtolower($css_title);
}
```

Comment: So, I implemented that function, but I'm getting errors when there is no page title available. Any adjustments that you'd recommend?

Comment: @Kellen – Depends on the errors and what pages exactly but I'd probably start with some basic if-else to catch that and provide a fallback?!

Comment: I'm not much of a programmer. I wouldn't know exactly what kind of if statement to apply. I expanded on my issue here if you can help: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/293487/injecting-page-title-as-css-class Thank you!

Comment: @Kellen – "Expects string but array given" says all. Then you only add the CSS class `if (!is_array($title)) {` and check on `} else {` what exactly is inside this array. Maybe the title then is inside `$title['value']`. You could install the Devel submodule Kint. And then do `ksm($title)`. Flush cache, flush cache and then you get the title variable pretty-printed on your page and you can inspect it.